# debian package dependency, how to set it for different version of ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian

My problem is our debian package require some other libs, but these libs on different version of ubuntu are named differently.

for example,

libgnutls26 ---  this can be found on ubuntu12.04, but not on ubuntu14.04 (probably libgnutls28 is used instead) . (please notice that it is only an example)

Is there a way that I can include it, then the correct version on both 12.04 and 14.04 version of ubuntu can be found?

Thanks,
LJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same question here!

The best work-around I have found is setting the dependency to the dev version (`libgnutls-dev` in your case). The development package depends on the compiled package and installs the proper version automatically. Sloppy but it works.

Comment: Thanks. It works. In fact, this is the way we used to do it. but now I am asked to take out all such lib***-dev things and use lib*** only. Thanks anyway, I think if I can not find another way to do it, maybe just use -dev.